# Erro ao realizar build no IONIC 3

Tags: ionic3

Estou codificando uma aplicação em IONIC 3 e ao tentar realizar o comando `ionic cordova run android` (Para poder realizar o debug da aplicação em meu celular) ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Running app-scripts build: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[18:28:12]  build dev started ... 
[18:28:12]  clean started ... 
[18:28:12]  clean finished in 15 ms 
[18:28:12]  copy started ... 
[18:28:12]  transpile started ... 
[18:28:15]  transpile finished in 2.74 s 
[18:28:15]  preprocess started ... 
[18:28:15]  deeplinks started ... 
[18:28:15]  deeplinks finished in 62 ms 
[18:28:15]  preprocess finished in 62 ms 
[18:28:15]  webpack started ... 
[18:28:15]  copy finished in 3.33 s 
[18:28:25]  webpack finished in 10.26 s 
[18:28:25]  sass started ... 
[18:28:27]  sass finished in 1.94 s 
[18:28:27]  postprocess started ... 
[18:28:27]  postprocess finished in less than 1 ms 
[18:28:27]  lint started ... 
[18:28:27]  build dev finished in 15.06 s 
[2K[G> cordova run android
[2K[GANDROID_HOME=C:\Android
[2K[GJAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
[2K[GSubproject Path: CordovaLib
[18:28:32]  lint finished in 5.52 s 
[2K[GStarting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[2K[G
[2K[GFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
[2K[GCould not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
[2K[G
[2K[G
[2K[G
[2K[G* Try:
[2K[G
[2K[GRun with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
[2K[G or --debug option to get more log output.
[2K[GError: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[2K[G
[2K[G
[2K[G[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[2K[G[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

Estou com o Android Studio instalado, e ao tentar realizar um debug em device por ele a aplicação é iniciada normalmente... O problema está em alguma configuração do ambiente do ionic mesmo...
Alguém saberia me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, mas consegui uma solução alternativa. Importar o projeto no Android Studio (tens de importar o build.gradle, ou settings.gradle) e iniciar o app por lá. Porém o app, ao menos no meu caso, não responde muito bem. Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução para esse problema seria aumentar a memória da mesma, você pode fazer isso adicionando uma nova variável de ambiente `_JAVA_OPTIONS` com o  valor `-Xmx512M`.

Uma outra alternativa é setar no `JAVA_HOME` uma versão x64 do Java.

**Referências:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346229/ionic-android-build-not-enough-memory-to-start-jvm
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1800